# how to setup terraform on MACOS for remote KVM host?

Tags: libvirt, source-code

I'm trying to configure this KVM provider on MAC, so I can provision VMs on a remote KVM server.

```
name: terraform-provider-libvirt
URL: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/terraform-provider-libvirt
```

installation went smooth with brew

```
# brew install terraform-provider-libvirt
```

I created a `provider.tf` file with code:

```
provider "libvirt" {
  alias = "kvm22"
  uri   = "qemu+ssh://kvm22/system"
}
```

then run,

```
# terraform init
```

it throws this error.

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider dmacvicar/libvirt: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
│ registry.terraform.io/dmacvicar/libvirt
```

how to make this libvirt provider work on a mac?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because this provider does not exist on registry.terraform.io.

Try this provider which is a fork of the former:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    libvirt = {
      source = "multani/libvirt"
      version = "0.6.3-1+4"
    }
  }
}

provider "libvirt" {
  alias = "kvm22"
  uri   = "qemu+ssh://kvm22/system"
}
```

You can get more details in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/multani/libvirt/latest/docs

Also, since you are getting the provider binary directly from  registry.terraform.io, you don't need `brew install terraform-provider-libvirt`